# Как с помощью pandas в Pythone сделать пробел в целом символе в эксель?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Работал с классами в экселе, ничего не предвещало беды, но с недавним обновлением эксель, он мои числа (к примеру 1 1001; 1 1002), превращает в одно целое (1 1001 -> 11001; или 1 1002 -> 11002). И это плохо, ведь эти классы мне нужны для матрицы, а значит в них должен быть пробел.

Что мне нужно: Какой нужен код на Python для того, чтобы к примеру ячейка с числом **111019** превратить в ячейку с числом **11 1019**, или **11001** превратить в **1 1001**?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы без __явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. как создать [mcve].

Comment: о каких классах речь?

Comment: думаю это не важно. Но этого для обучения нейронной сети. Класс подразумевает вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Что-то у меня длинновато получилось, но вроде работает:

```
for n in [111019, 11001]:
    n = str(n)
    print(''.join(f"{x}{('',' ')[not ((len(n) - 1 - i) % 4)]}" for i,x in enumerate(n)).strip())
```

Вывод:

```
11 1019
1 1001
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, спас

Comment: @RomanDunaev, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/)